# Bootstrap container or Well keep the well one size and enlarge text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fill a container, or a well, I believe the container will work better though. I need the container to stay the size it is in this [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3px20h6t/54/), but I need the Text to enlarge and stretch closer to the borders.

```
<div class="container-fluid color-back">
  <div style='font-size:2500%; color:orange; text-align: center'>
Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `transform: scale()`

Comment: would the transform: scale() go into my bootstrap.css file under the .container-fluid?

Comment: You can also use `.color-back`

Answer (score 1):

This is little harder to do but not impossible. You need to calculate the container width and set the fontsize accordingly. It is tricky since the font size will vary based on the number of characters in the text. A javascript based solution is probably easier to do. Did you look at something like http://fittextjs.com/?

For pure css based solution look in to vw and vh. They are not exactly fit for a container but based on viewport size.

Comment: I will have to look into this, it won't matter for the fontsize, the container will always have the exact same amount of characters in there.